# How to specify which docker-compose file to use (dev vs prod) when deploying NodeJS API on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a NodeJs API to ElasticBeanstalk but I'm dealing with the following issue:

I have two docker-compose files, one for dev and one for production environment. Is there any way I can setup which to execute on my environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Amazon Linux 2, you can use the [prebuild hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) to rename your production docker compose file. You can use `docker-compose.yml` to be for your development environment, and then create a file called `docker-compose.production.yml` for your production environment. Then create a local file `.platform/hooks/prebuild/docker_compose_cp.sh` that will get executed in the prebuild phase:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp docker-compose.production.yml docker-compose.yml
```

You should see output in the `eb-engine.log` during deployment indicating that the script has run:

```
[INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/prebuild/
[INFO] Following scripts will be executed in order: [docker_compose_cp.sh]
```